# What happens to changes for Autoscaling instances when terraform changes are made

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

Lets say I have an autoscaling group defined in terraform with min=2 and max=10.  Lets say, My ASG has kicked in and autoscaling is in progress and is currently at 6 instances.

Now I want to change my ASG to add another subnet and also want to change max=4. Would my current instances of 6 be unaffected? or would terraform reduces the instance count to 4 and add the new subnet as well when I run terraform apply.

Answer (score 0):

What happens depends on your setup. For now you just wrote that you have `min=2 and max=10`. What about `desired_capacity`?

Assuming standard setup that you start with `desired_capacity == min`, when your ASG is at 6 instances (i.e. its `desired_capacity=6` due to autoscaling activities) a `terraform apply` will **terminate** four instances and bring it back to `desired_capacity=2` as this is what you have in your terraform. Similar thing will happen if you set `max` to 4.

To combat this you would have to ignore changes to `desired_capacity` in your TF:

```
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [ desired_capacity ]
  }
```

> Would my current instances of 6 be unaffected?

No. Two would be terminated.

> would terraform reduces the instance count to 4 and add the new subnet as well when I run terraform apply.

Yes. That's would happen. But this will happen even if you don't change `max` as TF will set `desired_capacity` to what you have in your config files (unless explicitly ignored).

On top of that ASG may trigger **AZ re-balance** if a new subnet is in different AZ. ASG will try to spread your instance equally across AZs. So in this process, some can be terminated and re-launched in the new AZ.